# What is the best way to use the IF function in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I have a spreadsheet that is 166K rows and i need to write an IF function to fill in  a new column. I've tried 2 ways, one doesn't work and the other does but it takes forever to run. Any tips?

First attempt that didnt work:

```
lngLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

Range("S2").Formula = "=IF(Q2> DateValue("7/31/2021") then S2 = R2+30)"
Range("S2").Copy Range("S3:S" & lngLastRow)
```

Second attempt that worked but took forever to run:

```
For i = 2 To report.UsedRange.Rows.Coun

 If report.Cells(i, 17) > "7/31/2020" Then
  report.Cells(i, 19) = report.Cells(i, 18) + 30
 Else
  report.Cells(i, 19) = report.Cells(i, 18) 
 End If

 Next i
```

Lastly it actually looks like its not adding 30 to column 18 which is a date. I would like it to add 30 days to the date if the statement is true.

Comment: How long is "forever"?  What is the value of `report.UsedRange.Rows.Coun`?

Comment: `=IF(Q2> DateValue("7/31/2021") then S2 = R2+30)` isn't a valid worksheet formula. But you could adapt it into one and possibly avoid VBA altogether: `=IF(Q2>DATE(2021,31,7),R2+30,"")`.

Comment: you use `i` in your loop but `n` in your cells, Why?  Should they not be all `i`?

Comment: The second options just seems to run forever.. its gone 10 min and i just had to force close Excel. Yes i am an idiot, did mix of copy paste and typing and didnt pay attention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps the following:

```
Range("S2:S" & lngLastRow).Formula = "=IF(Q2>Datevalue(""7/31/2021""),30,0)+R2"
```

Using a `Variant` array is also an option:

```
Dim data() As Variant
data = Range("Q2:R" & lngLastRow).Value

Dim newData() As Variant
ReDim newData(1 to UBound(data,1), 1 to 1)

Dim i As Long
For i = LBound(data,1) to UBound(data,1)
    If data(i, 1) < DateValue("7/31/2021") Then
        newData(i, 1) = data(i, 2) + 30
    Else
        newData(i, 1) = data(i, 2)
    End If
Next

Range("S2:S" & lngLastRow).Value = newData
```